# lerna ERR! ZlibError: zlib: invalid block type while publishing packages in lerna

Tags: git, jenkins, npm, package.json, lerna

I am trying to publish my packages using `lerna publish` like this:

```
lerna publish prerelease --preid daily --yes --force-publish --registry <registry_url>
```

I have plugged this step in my Jenkins build pipeline as follows:

```
stage("setup enviornment") {
      steps {
            echo "\n[ ENV SET UP ]\n"
                ... Authentication Steps
            }
        }
stage("install packages") {
      steps {
        echo "\n[ INSTALLING PACKAGES ]\n"
        sh "yarn install"
      }
    }
stage("build packages") {
      steps {
        echo "\n[ BUILDING PACKAGES ]\n"
        sh "yarn build"
      }
    }
stage("Publish packages") {
      steps {
        echo "\n[ PUBLISHING PACKAGES ]\n"
        sh "yarn daily-deploy"
      }
    }
```

The script `daily-deploy` contains the lerna command as mentioned above.

However, I get the following error in the last step of publishing packages (private repository):

```
lerna info auto-confirmed 
lerna info execute Skipping releases
lerna info git Pushing tags...
lerna info publish Publishing packages to npm...
lerna notice Skipping all user and access validation due to third-party registry
lerna notice Make sure you're authenticated properly Â¯\_(ãƒ„)_/Â¯
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE Package <package name> is missing a license.
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE One way to fix this is to add a LICENSE.md file to the root of this repository.
lerna WARN ENOLICENSE See https://choosealicense.com for additional guidance.
lerna ERR! ZlibError: zlib: invalid block type
lerna ERR!     at Unzip.ZlibBase.(anonymous function).on.er (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:73:52)
lerna ERR!     at Unzip.emit (events.js:203:15)
lerna ERR!     at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:165:8)
lerna ERR!     at processChunkSync (zlib.js:403:12)
lerna ERR!     at Unzip.ZlibBase._processChunk (zlib.js:378:12)
lerna ERR!     at Unzip.write (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/minizlib/index.js:140:30)
lerna ERR!     at Object.write (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:305:58)
lerna ERR!     at Yallist.pipes.forEach.p (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:374:18)
lerna ERR!     at Yallist.forEach (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/yallist/yallist.js:156:8)
lerna ERR!     at ReadStream.emit (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:373:20)
lerna ERR!     at ReadStream.emit (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fs-minipass/index.js:154:22)
lerna ERR!     at ReadStream.write (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:163:17)
lerna ERR!     at ReadStream.[_handleChunk] (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fs-minipass/index.js:131:19)
lerna ERR!     at ReadStream.[_onread] (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fs-minipass/index.js:109:32)
lerna ERR!     at fs.read (/apps/agent/workspace/<project>-prerelease/node_modules/tar/node_modules/fs-minipass/index.js:101:22)
lerna ERR! lerna zlib: invalid block type
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have all private packages except for one.

My lerna.json is as below:

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent",
  "command": {
    "publish": {
      "registry": <repository_url>
    }
  },
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "useWorkspaces": true
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 with node v16 and npm 8 and lerna v4.0.0. First I thought it was related to https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2278, which spawned this issue: https://github.com/isaacs/minizlib/issues/8. I had a similar issue before (as you notice of those issues), but it went away. Now I am seeing these errors again :(

Comment: I've added a new comment on the original issue, for trackability: https://github.com/isaacs/minizlib/issues/8#issuecomment-990112556

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have a failed publish from `v1.1.0 -> v1.2.0` because a process that exited early, and I'm stuck with this zlib error message.

I tried re-run lerna publish and call `lerna version` separately:

```bash
  # Optional: Remove the broken version
  git reset --hard HEAD^  # Remove the last commit in local
  git tag -d v1.2.0  # Delete tag in local

  git push origin +master  # Push updates to remote/origin
  git push --delete origin v.1.2.0  # Delete tag in remote
  
  # Retry publish
  lerna version --force-publish  # This will create a commit, a tag, and push to git behind the scene
  
  git fetch origin master
  lerna publish from-git
```

Interestingly, I always fail when I tried to use the same number:
v1.1.0 -> v1.2.0 (fail)

v1.1.0 -> v1.1.1 (success) -> v1.2.0 (fail)

v1.1.0 -> v1.1.1 -> v1.2.1 (success)

So, I just accept the fact and skip that number instead.

P.S.: Difference between `lerna version` vs `lerna publish`, `--force-publish`, `from-git`  here: https://lerna.js.org/docs/features/version-and-publish#synchronized-versions

Another popular answer that is also worth trying:
https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2278#issuecomment-652538695

> ...
> Another thing you can do is defer git push until after a succesful
> publish:
>
> ```bash
> npx lerna version --no-push --yes 
> npx lerna publish from-git --yes
> # See https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/ea6ec639560ce71d9df8cbd7eef2d416e71f5442/commands/version/lib/git-push.js#L11
> git push --follow-tags --no-verify origin master
> ```